# Unable to deposit tokens in to smart contract

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts

I am a student who is currently studying about blockchain, currently i have a issue where i am unable to deposit my tokens to my smart contract. I am current using mist and using geth as ethereum client and truffle to deploy my smart contract. Is there any ways to solve the problem? Any answers will be appreciated

This shows that my account send to my smart contract address

[image: Picture above shows that my account send to my smart contract address,]

However smart contract ether is not incremented. Why so?

[image: However smart contract ether is not incremented ? Why so]

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

When sending ETH to smart contract directly, the contract's fallback function needs to be `payable`

```
contract Test {
    function() payable { // do something.. }
}
```